# google-cloud-run quarkus google-cloud-sql

Tags: google-cloud-sql, quarkus, google-cloud-run, quarkus-panache

I deploy a native quarkus application under cloud run. This application need to connect to a cloud sql postgresql database.
On the configuration panel's cloud run, i create a Cloud SQL connections (db-instance-name eq. cloud sql) and some variable as DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME
On Quarkus, i define properties as below :

```
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql:///${DBNAME}:5432
quarkus.datasource.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
quarkus.datasource.username=${DB_USER}
quarkus.datasource.password=${DB_PASSWORD}
```

My pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-orm-panache</artifactId>
</dependency>   
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-jdbc-postgresql</artifactId>
</dependency>    
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud.sql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgres-socket-factory</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.16</version>
</dependency>
```

When cloud run is starting, an exception occured :

```
WARN [io.agr.pool] (Agroal_18109070341) Datasource '<default>': Connection to :5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections
```

I have to say that cloud run is deployed by cloud build.

Could you help me to fix this issue... 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a `unix_socket` file looks like the following

```
postgres://user:password@/databasename?unix_sock=/cloudsql/projectshortcod:us-central1:pg-instance-name
```

you probably need to put this in the URL field of you library, but make sure that the library supports unix_socket databases.

Comment: You mean something like that "ERROR [org.hib.eng.jdb.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (main) Driver does not support the provided URL: jdbc:postgres://[user]:[pwd]@/[db-name]?unix_sock=/cloudsql/[db-connection-name]" ...

Comment: I think i could fix it with this https://github.com/jtama-op/quarkus/tree/18280ee018d82acef601fc022a5c6923bfb7a451/extensions/agroal ... but i don't know how to integrate to my project

Comment: I am not a Quarkus expert. Try to reach out to the github account holder and ask for guidance

Comment: Quarkus jdbc does not support yet socket connection. I have to install cloud sql proxy to fix this issue. Cf https://qiita.com/koduki/items/fa60e87e1d8bb28c2be4

Answer (score 0):

I got this working (for MySQL instead of Postgres; but should be similar) without using a `unix_socket`, but simply using a `quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql:///DB-NAME?ipTypes=PRIVATE&cloudSqlInstance=PROJECT-NAME:REGION:demo&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory` (and an `quarkus.datasource.username=` and `quarkus.datasource.password=`, as always).

The `?ipTypes=PRIVATE&` is [to connect to a Cloud SQL with only a private instead of a public IP](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-jdbc-socket-factory#specifying-ip-types) from within GCP; omit that if you want to connect to a public IP, e.g. from your developer machine at home or work.

The trickiest part wasn't so much this but [to set up all the required pre-requisites on GCP](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-jdbc-socket-factory/issues/375) for this connection to work from a Quarkus service running on AppEngine Standard.

[Quarkus Issue #9985](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/9985) is for about documenting this.